# How to design my servers database for my iOS application?

Tags: php, mysql, ios

I am developing an iOS application from which users can post various kinds of events in a server and view the events created from all the users. The question i have , does not have a programming nature. I would like to show here , how i would design my servers database and tell me your opinion about it and how i could improve it.

The application has a very simple interface where the user when he wants to post an event , simply writes a title , some comments and attaches a photo if he wants . Then this information is sent through XML to my server and stored to the database.

The problem is that because some people are immature , they would try to post inappropriate words or even photos. So i would like to have some control on my users. What i am thinking is , at the first time that the application runs on the mobile phone and connects to the server , the server would send a user id back to the phone. Then every time the users sends an xml file , he attaches his user id with the xml (programatically attached). Also i would keep another database with all the user ids that have been created over time. So if i notice an inappropriate event , i could delete the user id from my database , and the next time the user tries to send something, the server would understand that this id is not in the database and so not allow the posting. Of course if someone decides to uninstall and reinstall the application and get a new user id , he could again post but thats ok with me.

Would it be an easier way to prevent immature behaviors or this one sounds ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure what you describe is possible. But there is one big problem with it: that interface can easily be used by a robot (a script). So if someone *really* wants to missuse your service, he can flood you with whatever he likes in a second. Or he can try again and again, until you have to give up removing his posts from the service.

I suggest you take a look at one of the existing frameworks instead. This way you do not have to reinvent the wheel (which has already been done 19562394792 times, and counting) and don't have to learn from your mistakes (which you certainly will make).

Comment: You can put a script on an iphone application? Also the interface is not that simple as i describe. i described it like this to give a general idea. There are many categories , submenus etc etc to choose from.

Comment: Well you can only expect a reply to what you ask, right? You mentioned an interface design, I replied to that. Apart from that: why can your interface only be used from an iphone? Has Apple even got it's own internet now? Ah, right, Obviously Apple has patented the internet now...

Comment: Because its an iphone app , not a web-browsing app. Maybe i create a web page for showing the events but not for posting. I cant understand your sarcarm... Many applications work only through the iphone and don't provide a web-based solution...That doesn't mean anything..

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the sarcasm, does not belong here. But a question: how does your app comunicate with your service, if not via internet? What should keep any other process/system to use that interface? Just because _you_ don't offer any other means beside that app does not mean nobody else can create such a solution.

Comment: You are right. BUT how easy is for someone to see where my iphone connects to? And even if he does how is he going to see my xml's form? Cause in order to save the event to the database you need to send the exact same form that my database accepts. And not to mention you need to have the user id which is only send to the iphone , encrypted. So someone needs to completely reverse engineer it. I dont think anyone will , cause it will be a free application so it doesnt worth the effort.

Comment: Usually you find out about an interface or protocol by simply sniffing the network traffic. And about the encryption: how does that work? Without a preshared key there is no way to setup a secure encryption without that this setup can be sniffed to, since it is part of the communication. And I didn't see any such key scheme in your description.

Comment: About that userid as a protection: provided that those ids are complex and really hard to guess (you cannot simply count numbers up for this) then this might offer some basic protection against missusage. However a) that id can be sniffed too, since it is sent as part of the communication and b) a brute force attempt simply trying ids will bring your server down. Though I agree that this might not be a problem for such a service.

Comment: I use an encryption mechanism in my application to send the user id to the database along with the xml file. The database(php) decrypts the key and stores the event if is correct. So how can someone decrypt it without knowing the encryption mechanisms?

Comment: That means that that "encryption" is a static one, the same for all clients, since no key or anything is exchanged or used. That means the encryption can easily be reversed by statistical methods. That _is_ possible and not that difficult. You should call it obfuscation, not encryption. But granted again that this might not be a real problem for what you plan.

Comment: Well you might be right on this , but this kind of security level would simply be "too much" for an application like this , just to prevent someone from flooding the database. Seems too much work to me for just a free application don't you think? And the individual trying to do that must be a good hacker. I am a computer engineer working as a researcher and have absolutely NO IDEA how i could do this. Than must mean that the average user has no idea too how to do this. Its not a bank app to provide that kind of security but thank you for your advice :)

Comment: But because you mentioned it now i am very curious. How can someone see where my iphone connects and what kind of data it exhanges?

Comment: As said: I agree that this might not be a real problem for the service you plan. If the app is free or not is irrelevant in this. Typically especially free solutions (Free/OpenSource Software) offer the best security level and are used for really critical missions. What you mean is that the effort is too high compared to the reward you get when missusing it. There is nothing to be gained. That is true, we agree there.

Comment: How to snif the communication on an ios device: same as on every other system, you use a network sniffer. There are free ones and commercial ones available, just google for it. Also this could be done on the server side, but that is more complex, indeed :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22941/discussion-between-donparalias-and-arkascha)

Comment: I absoutely agree that for the service you offer one should keep the effort of implementation inside certain borders... However, if you want to enhance you encryption, then combine your identity token ("user id") with a second entrophy vector like a time based token and/or a challenge response scheme. Though both approaches are not bulletproof they reliably prevent attacks on the encryption that are based on plain statitics. Simply because the encryption key is different for each request. Both schemes are documented, easy start would be wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password

Comment: For the framework: sorry, I never used an iPhone, so I cannot provide any experience. My arguments came from a general point of view which certainly is also valid for iPhone based solutions, since these systems do not differ in any technical principle from other systems (mobile or not). All web frameworks come with finished solutions or plugins for this, but you are looking for a client side implementation, I guess. You might be interested in this: http://motp.sourceforge.net/ as one existing solution that comes with a short description on how to use it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23056/discussion-between-donparalias-and-arkascha)

Answer (score 1):

This is about the only workable solution with images since you can't easily perform any recognition on an image to decide if it is appropriate. The comments they post would be more easily scanned for inappropriate items.

If you are will to do this kind of moderation then your solution sounds like the right one. As with any open system you can't really stop people from creating new accounts as you mentioned. You could log and ban IP addresses, but that is not a very good solution anymore as most IP addresses could really be shared gateway addresses and those addresses rotate frequently between users.

Create an ID. Watch for behavior. Ban the ID. And encourage community involvment in alerting you of bad posts with some kind of a Flag button.

Comment: Thank you davidethell. Well i will put a flag next to all events so users can help me find any inappropriate behavior. Also i could permantly ban the user by using his phone IMEI number as a user id which is unique for every iphone , but i dont want to keep and kind of personal information in my database.

Comment: Yes, that's right, you really don't want to save the unique id or even other items associated with their device like the IMEI or Mac Address. Apple already rejects apps because they use or abuse information like this so best to stay away from it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to design a database and not just for use with an iOS app. However when I'm building a mobile app (iOS, Android or any other) I want to make sure that the amount of data being sent and received is as small as possible; this is why I use JSON instead of XML... smaller footprint.

Because I use JSON I like to use an object database like MongoDB (my favorite) or CouchDB, because I 1) don't need to worry about the structure of my data and 2) the database stores the objects in JSON format.

I then use Node.JS for my application server so now I have JSON database -> JSON objects in my server application code -> outputting JSON... seamless with no Mappers or serialisation required. FTW.

Comment: The xml files are like 1kb each in size. I dont think i ll have any problem with my bandwidth. How smaller can a json file be? Also i have worked much with xml files , so i have parsers ready for everything. But thank you for your answer!